# a minimal working `kappa` sample for Python deployment to AWS Lambda

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, kappa

I'm trying to use `kappa` to make seamless deployments to AWS Lambda.

I tried modifying the [S3 Sample](https://github.com/garnaat/kappa/tree/develop/samples/s3) to upload a python code instead. I created the Lambda by running `kappa ./config.yml create` (after replacing the profile with my [aws console profile](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)). The lambda is created and is shown in the AWS Function dashboard, as shown in picture:

[image]

I now want to convert this sample to generate a new lambda, but of Python runtime. The python file is:

`examplefolder/hello_world.py`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json

print('Loading function')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    print("value1 = " + event['key1'])
    print("value2 = " + event['key2'])
    print("value3 = " + event['key1'])
    return event['key2']  # Echo back the first key value
    #raise Exception('Something went wrong')
```

Then I modified the lambda relevant section on `config.yml`:

```
lambda:
  name: S3PythonSample
  zipfile_name: S3PythonSample.zip
  description: Testing S3 Lambda Python handler
  path: examplefolder/
  handler: hello_lambda.lambda_handler
  runtime: python
```

I then run `kappa ./config.yml create` again to create the new Lambda, but I get this error:

```
$ kappa ./config.yml create 
creating...
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py:251: SecurityWarning: Certificate has no `subjectAltName`, falling back to check for a `commonName` for now. This feature is being removed by major browsers and deprecated by RFC 2818. (See https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/497 for details.)
  SecurityWarning
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py:251: SecurityWarning: Certificate has no `subjectAltName`, falling back to check for a `commonName` for now. This feature is being removed by major browsers and deprecated by RFC 2818. (See https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/497 for details.)
  SecurityWarning
        Unable to upload zip file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kappa/function.py", line 162, in create
    MemorySize=self.memory_size)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 258, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 312, in _make_api_call
    raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 'python' at 'runtime' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy enum value set: [nodejs]
        Unable to add permission
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kappa/function.py", line 141, in add_permissions
    response = self._lambda_svc.add_permission(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 258, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 312, in _make_api_call
    raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is from botocore's 2014-11-11 API definitions, which means you don't have the 2015-03-31 update.

You should be able to `pip install -U botocore` to update and try again.